# Laravel route list returns error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

When i try to show list of available routes artisan returns the following error:

```
   $ php artisan route:list

      [ReflectionException]
      Class API does not exist
```

It worked a while ago but now i can't get it to work.

Laravel version is:

```
$ php artisan -V
Laravel Framework version 5.1.10 (LTS)
```

Is it possible to debug somehow this error?

Comment: Did you try clearing your compiled list?

Comment: Did you try composer dump-autoload?

Comment: yes i tried clear-compiled and composer dump-autoload. doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find what's wrong in the `storage/logs/laravel-YYYY-MM-DD.log` file.

Check it, resolve and run artisan again.

Comment: thanks a lot, i found unused routes. after fixing it route:list doesn't return an error.

Answer (score 1):

What's your php version ? I think, if you are under php5.5, then change the shell.

Comment: it worked with the current php version: PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:29:28)